# Convert HTTP_Request2 to wp_remote_post

Tags: wp-remote-post

I have some php in WordPress using HTTP_Request2 that I'm struggling to convert to use wp_remote_post.

This code currently works:

```php
$xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID = '
    <GetCustomerDataByAuthor>
        <AuthorID>ABC123</AuthorID>
    </GetCustomerDataByAuthor>';
$requestDataLicense = new HTTP_Request2(
     $urlCustomerDataByAuthor,HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
$requestDataLicense->addPostParameter(
    'xml', $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID);  
$requestDataLicenseResponse = $requestDataLicense->send();
$xmlDataParsed = simplexml_load_string(
    $requestDataLicenseResponse->getBody());
    
foreach ($xmlDataParsed->{"Customer"} as $individualCustomer)
{
   $customerEmail = strtolower(trim($individualCustomer->Email));
}
```

This is my failed attempt:

```
$requestDataLicenseResponse = wp_remote_post(
        $urlCustomerDataByAuthor, 
        array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
            ),
            'body' => array('xml' => $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID),
            'sslverify' => false
        )
    );
$xmlDataParsed = simplexml_load_string($requestDataLicenseResponse ->getBody());

foreach ($xmlDataParsed->{"Customer"} as $individualCustomer)
    {
       $customerEmail = strtolower(trim($individualCustomer->Email));
    }
```

The expect input for the service is

```
<GetCustomerDataByAuthor xmlns="">
<AuthorID>value</AuthorID>
</GetCustomerDataByAuthor>
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting on your code by fixing the indenting so it was readable but didn't get very far, can you edit it to make it easier to read? It looks like there are chunks missing, e.g. your first line has a string that got cut off and isn't complete

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with how you're passing the `XML data` in the request body. In the `wp_remote_post` function try this"

```
    $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID = '<GetCustomerDataByAuthor><AuthorID>ABC123</AuthorID></GetCustomerDataByAuthor>';

$response = wp_remote_post(
    $urlCustomerDataByAuthor,
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
        ),
        'body' => $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID,
        'sslverify' => false
    )
);

if (wp_remote_success($response)) {
    $xmlDataParsed = simplexml_load_string($response['body']);

    foreach ($xmlDataParsed->{"Customer"} as $individualCustomer) {
        $customerEmail = strtolower(trim($individualCustomer->Email));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank Lewis for the response.  
Couple items:  
1. I get a "Call to undefined function wp_remote_success()"  
2. I printed out the $response and I see " [body] => Request format is invalid: text/xml. [response] => Array ( [code] => 500 [message] => Internal Server Error "

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
$requestDataLicense = new HTTP_Request2($urlCustomerDataByAuthor,HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
$requestDataLicense->addPostParameter('xml', $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID);    
$requestDataLicenseResponse = $requestDataLicense->send();
$xmlDataParsed = simplexml_load_string($requestDataLicenseResponse->getBody())
```

converts to

```
$requestDataLicense = wp_remote_post(
    $urlCustomerDataByAuthor,
    array(
        'body' => array('xml' => $xmlCustomerDataByAuthorLicenseID)
    )
);      

$retrieveBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body($requestDataLicense);
$xmlDataParsed = simplexml_load_string($retrieveBody);
```